# Put semicolons in asi mode before brackets

Tags: javascript, jshint, automatic-semicolon-insertion

I'm linting my JavaScript with JSHint, and have this option enabled

```
"asi": true,
"white": true
```

to avoid semicolons in my code.

But I have to begin my new line with a bracket, so I have to put a semicolon before the opening of that one

```
;(function () {

})
```

JSHint give me two errors:

- *Missing space after ';'*
- If I put a space after ';' I get: *Expected '(' to have a different identation*

I noticed that in this way JSHint is happy

```
;
(function () {

})
```

but I think is not a good solution.

Is there a way to solve this problem, without turning off JSHint or the *white* option?

Comment: Is it worth all this trouble to avoid having to type semicolons?

Comment: There are good reasons why avoiding automatic semi-colon insertion is recommended

Comment: The point of JSHint isn't just to validate that you are writing javascript that parses. You can just try running it for that. While there's certainly different philosophies on ASI, when it comes to writing one really ugly construct to avoid another one, is it really better? Putting a semicolon before a function def is a workaround in the first place, it seems legit that JSHint wouldn't validate it.

Comment: guys i really care and understand your point of view, but this isn't a debate about the semicolon insertion, it's about a jshint warning =)

Comment: Are you using any other JSHint options? Because I am not getting those errors when using jshint.com.

Comment: @GeorgeP my problem is related to the white: true option, i was wondering if there is a way to keep it true without getting the warning i was writing about

Comment: What does *"asi"* mean? E.g., is it an abbreviation for something? ASI: [automatic semicolon insertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Whitespace_and_semicolons)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The legacy `white: true` option in JSHint is used to enforce the coding style promoted by [Douglas Crockford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Crockford) in his original [JSLint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSLint) tool.  Semicolon-less JavaScript code will not fit his coding style. If you don't want to be restricted to his style guidelines then don't use `white: true`.

[This list of JSHint options](http://www.jshint.com/options/) doesn't show any parameters to customize the coding style they enforce.

To prove that there isn't an answer to this, I went and found the relevant check in the JSHint source:

```
function nonadjacent(left, right) {
    if (option.white) {
        left = left || token;
        right = right || nexttoken;
        if (left.line === right.line && left.character === right.from) {
            left.from += (left.character - left.from);
            warning("Missing space after '{a}'.",
                    left, left.value);
        }
    }
}
```

The only configuration option checked is `option.white`, so unfortunately there isn't any way to achieve your desired behavior. If you really wanted a tool that would do exactly what you want, you could easily fork [JSHint](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/), add another option, and check it in the `nonadjacent` function.